# looping three php arrays

Tags: arrays, loops

I have three PHP arrays and I want to use them in the same loop to get the values.

```
$advertising_advpic   = "photo src1,photo src2,photo src3";
$advertising_advlink  = "site link1,site link2,site link3";
$advertising_advtitle = "site name1,site name2,site name3";

$advpic   = explode(",",$advertising_advpic);
$advlink  = explode(",",$advertising_advlink);
$advtitle = explode(",",$advertising_advtitle);


for ( $i = 0; $i<count($advpic); $i++)
{
    $link  = $advlink [$i];
    $pic   = $advpic  [$i];
    $title = $advtitle[$i];
    $all   = "<td nowrap><a target='_blank' href='".$link."'><img src='".$pic."' border='0' alt='".$title."'></a></td>";
}
```

But when I print `$all` I only get the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$advertising_advpic   = "photo src1,photo src2,photo src3";
$advertising_advlink  = "site link1,site link2,site link3";
$advertising_advtitle = "site name1,site name2,site name3";

$advpic = explode(",",$advertising_advpic);
$advlink = explode(",",$advertising_advlink);
$advtitle = explode(",",$advertising_advtitle);
$all = "";

for ( $i = 0; $i<count($advpic); $i++)
{
    $link   = $advlink[$i];
    $pic = $advpic[$i];
    $title  = $advtitle[$i];
    $all = $all . "<td nowrap><a target='_blank' href='".$link."'><img src='".$pic."' border='0' alt='".$title."'></a></td>";
}
```

The way you had it before you were continually reassinging $all every iteration of the loop.